# How to achieve directory upload in kendo ui angular2?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-upload

I used [this link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/#toc-batch), but I couldn't find the document or sample for directory upload in angular2. Can you please suggest on how to achieve it?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?